# Get value from text field input without form

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

Im trying to send via ajax a value from a textfield, but don't want to use a form , don't think is needed:

```
name = document.getElementByName["icall"].value;
alert( "Data Saved: " + name );
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "ajaxload/icall.php",
data: "numero="+name
}).done(function( msg ) {
alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

This is the primary function, bellow is the html markup:

```
<div class="conteudo">
            <span class="numero">O seu numero:</span><input type="text" name="icall" class="teximput" size="30"></input>
            <p><span class="avisome">Precisa de ajuda com algo? Nos ligamos consigo na proxima hora!</span></p>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="ligarme();"><span class="botaoliga"></span></a>
        </div>
```

Shouldn't this be enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var name = $(".teximput").val();
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "ajaxload/icall.php",
data: "numero="+name,
success:function(msg) {
alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, actually, the $("#icall") wouldn't work because it's not a div with that atribute, but $(".teximput") worked like a charm. How could i not use jQuery for this, so simple.
By the way, the merit is yours, so selected as the right answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementByName["icall"].value
```

is incorrect.  The function is getElement*s*ByName.  Also, Instead of square brakets, use parentheses for function calls:

```
document.getElementsByName("icall")[0].value
```